# Looking for a way to assign a Char * to a Char

Tags: c, char

So basically I will be taking in 4 chars in something like this:

```
char color1 = 'y';
```

and what I would like to do is:

```
char *newcolor = color1;
```

Basically I'll be given a `y` and I'd like to store it into my `char *` so that I can concatenate the characters so be a `char * colorpattern` and look something like this `ygpb` as letters representing a color.

Hoping there is an easy way to assign it and if there isn't ill go try and find a way to store the values into a `char *` in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that `char*` is not a well-defined type -- it may be a pointer to a char, it may be a pointer to a null-terminated character array (a "string"), or it may point to nothing at all, and you have to set it before you can "assign" any char values to it.  The "back story" of `char*` is critical.

Comment: If you are at this level of C development, you should really take a course or read a book on it. http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Plus-5th-Stephen-Prata/dp/0672326965

Comment: Bah! C is only messy if you make it messy... you can do that with any language. It can also be incredibly elegant. The issue is the programmer, not the language.

Comment: @HotLicks: `char*` is a perfectly well defined type. It's a pointer to `char`. (Depending on what value you store it an object of type `char*`, it might be a pointer to (the first character of) a string).

Comment: @HotLicks I've never found C confusing. And I don't know assembly.

Comment: Please don't refer to `char` as `Char`. C is case-sensitive; `Char` could conceivably be the name of a different type.

Comment: `char` is a perfectly well-defined type, but `char*` is incredibly ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

#### What you want:

Given a character, make it a string.

#### How to solve it:

Store it in an array and NUL-terminate:

```
char str[5];
str[0] = 'y';
str[1] = 'g';
str[2] = 'b';
str[3] = 'p';
str[4] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to declare a buffer with enough space to hold not only the single `'y'` byte, but also the stuff you want to add to it and the null terminator...

```
char color1[5] = "y";

strcat( color1, "g" );
strcat( color1, "p" );
strcat( color1, "b" );
```

Or, in one swell foop which you could later overwrite...

```
char color1[5] = "ygpb";
```

You do not need to assign the `char` to a `char*` to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Didn't downvote but you said, "only the byte". It's a little unclear maybe to the OP what that means. I know you mean null-terminating character.